# Must I use the new Enhanced Auth Dialog to ask for publish_actions permission?

Tags: facebook, permissions

I have a an existing application, and to which I'd like to add publish_actions permissions. Does this require using the Enhanced Auth Dialog?

Comment: I would like to know this also, and it would appear so from what everyone else is saying.

Comment: Yes it does seem to be the case you need the enhanced auth dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this [documenation](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/04/25/streamlining-publish_stream-and-publish_actions-permissions/) I read:

> In addition to providing a description, publish_actions will now
>   include basic publish_stream permissions (including posting on a
>   user's timeline, posting photos/videos, commenting on and liking
>   content), which will appear on the first Auth Dialog screen.

[...]

> We recommend all apps use publish_actions following this change. If
>   you need specific capabilities like posting to a friend's timeline or
>   to groups, you will still need to request publish_stream, which
>   appears on a second screen where users can also opt out. When asking
>   for permissions, consider the user experience and impact to
>   conversion. We have found that the more permissions you request –
>   especially those such as publish_stream that prompt a second Auth
>   Dialog screen – the lower your conversion rate will be.

So yes, I guess this is a clue that you need to use the enhanced auth dialog. (in most of the case including a publish_stream permission).

Answer (score -1):

You can only ask for this permission if 1) you are a developer of the app or 2) you have actions approved for your app by facebook

Yeah, it makes it kind of difficult to test

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I asked which dialog to invoke.